# Django and python, how to get a annotate from two different model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have the following model framework:

```
class Subcategory(models.Model):
    nome=models.CharField()

class Order(models.Model):
    order=models.CharField()

class Quantity(models.Model):
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order)
    subcategory=models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    quantity=models.DecimalField()

class Price(models.Model):
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order)
    subcategory=models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    price=models.DecimalField()
```

Now I want to obtain a new value that give me the possibility to filter for `subcategory` and `order` both `price` and `quantity` queryset and give me the moltiplication of them.
this is the code that I have set, but I don't know how obtain the `price*quantity` operation.

```
cod='1234'
price=dict()
defaults=list(0 for m in range(1))
filter_quantity = list(Quantity.objects.values_list('subcategory__id', flat=True).distinct()).filter(order__order=cod)
    
    for subcategory__id, totals in(Price.objects.filter(
        subcategoty__in=filter_quantity ).values_list('subcategory__id').annotate(totals=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('price')),
                output_field=FloatField())).values_list('subcategory__id', 'totals'):
                if subcategory__id not in price.keys():
                    price[subcategory__id ]=list(defaults)
                index=0
                price[subcategory__id][index]=totals
total_costs={'Costs': [sum(t) for t in zip(*price.values())]}
```

Comment: So you want to annotate the `Quantity`?

Comment: yep I want to obtain the moltiplication of quantity*price based on value filled for subcategory and order

Comment: Is does not seem to make much sense, since an order can have multiple `Quantity`s and multiple `Price`s, so there is no 1-1 mapping.

Comment: The price must be filtered for order and subcategory that are present in quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make changes to this method according to your need.

```
def get_order_details(order_code):
    order_details = []
    quantities = Quantity.objects.filter(order__order=order_code)
    prices_queryset = Price.objects.filter(order__order=order_code)

    for quantity in quantities:
        price = prices_queryset.filter(order__order=order_code, subcategory=quantity.subcategory).first()
        if price:
            order_details.append({
                'subcategory_name': quantity.subcategory.nome,
                'quantity': quantity.quantity,
                'unit_price': price.price,
                'total_price': quantity.quantity * price.price
            })

    return {
        'order_code': order_code,
        'details': order_details
    }
```